Random Walks and Their Solutions - Bedeaux.
I am reading a paper by Bedeaux et al. titled "On the Relation Between Master Equations and Random Walks and their Solutions." The paper is on relation between solution of Random Walks vs Master Equation based solution.
They consider Random walks where the walker takes steps at times $t_i$. The Random variables $T_i = t_i - t_{i-1}$ are distributed according a density $\psi(T)$.
The general equation for the Random Walk : $P(\alpha; n+1) = \sum_{\alpha^\prime} M_{\alpha \alpha^\prime} P(\alpha^\prime; n) = \mathbf{M} P(\alpha;n)$, where $P(\alpha;n)$ is the probability that the walker is in state $\alpha$ after the $n^{th}$ step. $M_{\alpha \alpha^\prime}$ is the probability that the walker transitions from $\alpha$ to $\alpha^\prime$ in one step.
The general form of he master equation is,
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} Q(\alpha; t) = \sum_{\alpha^\prime} Q(\alpha^\prime;t) = \mathbf{A} Q(\alpha, t)$.
Where $Q(\alpha;t)$ is the probability that the system is in state $\alpha$ at time $t$, $A_{\alpha \alpha^\prime}$ is the transtion rate from state $\alpha^\prime$ to $\alpha$. $\mathbf{A}$ is the transition rate matrix.
The formal solution to the Random Walk equation: $P(\alpha;n) = \mathbf{M}^n P(\alpha; 0)$.
The generating function for the random walk: $P(\alpha; z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n P(\alpha;n) = (I - z\mathbf{M})^{-1} P(\alpha;0)$.
Corresponding Green's functon: $G_{\alpha \alpha^\prime} = (I - z\mathbf{M})^{-1} \delta_{\alpha \alpha^\prime}$
The continuous time sulution to the random walk problem is given by:
$P(\alpha; t) = \sum_0^\infty \Phi_t(n) P(\alpha; n)$
Where $\Phi_t(n)$ is the probability that the walker made exactly $n$ steps at time $t$. This probability is related to the probability density $\psi_n(t)$that the walker makes his $n^{th}$ step at time $t$, $t = t_n$, by
$\Phi_t(n) = \int_0^t \psi_n(\tau) \int_{t-\tau}^\infty \psi(\tau^\prime) d\tau^\prime d\tau$,
$\psi_n(t) = \int_0^t \psi_{n-1}(\tau) \psi(t - \tau) d\tau, \quad n > 1$
$\psi_1(t) = \psi(t)$, $\psi_0(t) = \delta(t)$.
The generating function for the random walk as a function of time is defined as:
$P(\alpha; s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st} P(\alpha; t) dt$
Now he writes (using all the equations we so far listed) the equation for $P(\alpha; s)$ as,
$P(\alpha;s) = \left( s - \frac{s \tilde{\psi}(s)}{1 - \tilde{\psi}(s)} (\mathbf{M} - I)\right)^{-1} P(\alpha; 0)$
Where $\tilde{\psi}(s) = \int_0^\infty \psi(t) e^{-st} dt$
I am stumped as to how he arrived at this last equation. My derivation is far from it. What I get is a completely different result. Here it is,
$
\begin{align}
P(\alpha; s) &= \int_0^\infty e^{-st} P(\alpha; t) dt
= \int_0^\infty e^{-st} \sum_0^t \Phi_t(n) P(\alpha; n) dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-st} \sum_0^\infty P(\alpha; n) \int_0^t \psi_n(\tau) \int_{t - \tau}^\infty \psi(\tau^\prime) d\tau^\prime d\tau dt
\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(\alpha;n) \int_0^\infty \int_0^t \psi_n(\tau) \left[ 1 - \int_0^{t-\tau} \psi(\tau^\prime) d\tau^\prime \right] e^{-st} d \tau dt
\end{align} 
$
We do a bit of change of variables here, $t - \tau = u$ and obtain,
$
\begin{align}
P(\alpha;s) &= \sum_0^\infty P(\alpha;n)  \left[ \frac{\psi_n(s)}{s} - \int_0^\infty \int_0^t \psi_n(t - u) \int_0^u \psi(\tau^\prime) e^{-st} d\tau^\prime du dt\right] \\
& =\sum_0^\infty P(\alpha;n) \left[\frac{\psi_n(s)}{s} - \frac{\psi_n(s) \psi(s)}{s^2}\right] \\
&= \sum_0^\infty P(\alpha;n) \frac{\psi_n(s)}{s^2} \left[s - \psi(s)\right] 
\end{align}
$
Now we note that $\psi_n(s) = [\psi(s)]^n$ by convolution. I end up with,
$\frac{s - \psi(s)}{s^2} \sum_0^\infty P(\alpha;n) [\psi(s)]^n$. I am also not sure about the convolution integral that I simplified, $\int_0^\infty \int_0^t \psi_n(t - u) \int_0^u \psi(\tau^\prime) e^{-st} d\tau^\prime du dt = \frac{\psi_n(s) \psi(s)}{s^2}$. I think it should have been $\frac{\psi_n(s) \Psi(s)}{s}$, where $\Psi(u) = \int_0^u \psi(\tau^\prime) d\tau^\prime$. This, I can do by writing $\int_0^t \int_0^{t - \tau} \psi_n(\tau) \psi(\tau^\prime) d\tau^\prime d\tau$ as $\int_0^t \psi_n(\tau) \Psi(t - \tau) d\tau$.
Essentially, what I get is very different from what is in the paper. I am also not sure how that convolution integral works out. I would extremely appreciate it if someone could explain it to me as to what I am doing wrong and what I am missing?
